# Regex pattern to identify column names in an SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, regex

I am looking for resources on how to build a regex pattern to match column names from an `SQL` **WHERE** clause.

I have the SQL SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE area = 'testarea' AND description = 'testdescription' AND ...
```

And I'm trying to extract the terms **area** and **description**, and any others following `AND`s. I understand this can get more complicated as the `WHERE` clause gets more complicated, but for now, I'm assuming that it conforms to the structure in the example.

When I try to search the web for examples on how to do this, I only see examples of how to include regex in the WHERE clause, but not actually match against it.

*Can someone help me get started here?* I'm at a loss.

Comment: where is the statement stored? what's the dbms being used?

Comment: DB is MS SQL Server. Not sure that would matter though, right? The `WHERE` structure is the same as MySQL and others.

Comment: What if the condition is `'testarea' = area`?  Or `'abc' in (x, y, z)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm assuming that the structure of the WHERE clause is `col1 = 'value' AND ...`.

Comment: dbms matters because `regex` isn't supported in *all* of them. SQL Server doesn't support it, which is what you are using.

Comment: I'm not looking to run the regex inside the statement. I'm looking to use the select statement as the input to a regex matcher in code. But I'm having trouble defining the pattern.

Comment: Is dynamic SQL can be as an option?